# AngularJS + Nginx so 404 returns 404 and direct child route access returns AngularJS index file

Tags: angularjs, docker, nginx

I've been trying to find a solution for this for a while now but no luck so far. So here I am asking the question on Stackoverflow, hoping to get some questions answered.

I have an AngularJS app and an Angular app. They both need to be served from one Docker using one Nginx config. This is what I have so far in terms of Nginx config

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location ^~ /legacy/ {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

That `/legacy` route is where all the AngularJS stuff is. So normally when user visits my site they should be taken to Angular app. However if they explicitly go to `/legacy` URL, they will get AngularJS app. Sounds simple enough, however because of my lack of knowledge in Nginx, I have not been able to achieve this.

Right now, `/legacy` takes me to the correct `index.html` file but that file is trying to load an asset that doesnt exist (btw I can't edit any of the legacy code so removing this asset is out of question), in that case instead of returning 404 Nginx returns `index.html` itself. Which makes sense because of `try_files` directive. So I tried removing `try_files` directive and simply relied on `autoindex on` which worked fine when user went to just `/legacy` url. It stopped working when user directly tried to access a child route of legacy such as `/legacy/home`.

So my question would be, what changes do I need to make on the Nginx config side so that a missing asset would just throw 404 and when user dicrectly tried to access any child route of legacy (i.e `/legacy/home`) it would return the `index.html` from legacy directory.

Comment: If the URI for asset files end with `.js` and `.css` etc., you can add a separate location to process those requests, for example: `location ~ \.(css|js)$ { }`

Comment: @RichardSmith Oh ok. I can try that out. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able achieve this by adding a new location route on top of the `/legacy` location block as suggested by @Richard in the comment. I also made some more changes based on my needs. Here is the final config that I am currently using.

```
server {
    keepalive_timeout 300s;
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    port_in_redirect off;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|json|xml|txt) {
    }

    location ~ ^/legacy(?:/(.*))?$ {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html /index.html =404;
    }
}
```